# Azure Mobile Apps specific properties of entity in TableController

Tags: c#, azure, mobile

With Azure Mobile Apps we can synchronise between tables. I'm building multiple apps with different purposes. The other apps does not need all the properties of a specific table, only the once he needs. Is it possible to return only specific properties of a table from the Web API to the Client? If this is possible, when I push only the properties to the Web API that the Client is using. Will this affect the table data only for those properties?

I already searched on websites like, but could not find this:
https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/
https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is helpful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communites who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to return only specific properties of a table from the Web API to the Client?

Yes, The Azure Mobile Apps SDK supports quite a bit of OData v3 specification, we could use select specific fiedls by using the `$select` clause. More details please refer to [Data Access Concepts](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/dataconcepts/#filtering-data).

> when I push only the properties to the Web API that the Client is using. Will this affect the table data only for those properties?

We could do that. On my opinion ,if we want to upate part of all the properties then we may need to include the [id field](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/dataconcepts/#the-id-field) and the [version field](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/dataconcepts/#the-version-field). `Id` field file makes the table entity globally unique.The `Version` field is all about conflict detection.

If there is any conflict, we could use our logic to handle the conflict. More detail info please refer to [Handling Conflict Resolution](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#handling-conflict-resolution). The following is demo code from the document.

```
sync Task ResolveConflictAsync(MobileServiceTableOperationError error)
{
    var serverItem = error.Result.ToObject<T>();
    var localItem = error.Item.ToObject<T>();

    // Note that you need to implement the public override Equals(TodoItem item)
    // method in the Model for this to work
    if (serverItem.Equals(localItem))
    {
        // Items are the same, so ignore the conflict
        await error.CancelAndDiscardItemAsync();
        return;
    }

    // Client Always Wins
    localItem.Version = serverItem.Version;
    await error.UpdateOperationAsync(JObject.FromObject(localItem));

    // Server Always Wins
    // await error.CancelAndDiscardItemAsync();
}
```